# How to order endpoints by httpmethod in swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

at the moment I am trying to order by controller endpoints by httpmethod. **Get/Post/Put/Delete**
[image]

I'm looking for a way to achieve this without using tags which is illustrated in this post [How to order endpoints based on actions in swagger using .Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71173124/how-to-order-endpoints-based-on-actions-in-swagger-using-net-core).

I've tried

```
options.OrderActionsBy((apiDesc) => $"{apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["controller"]}_{apiDesc.HttpMethod}");
```

and

```
options.OrderActionsBy((apiDesc) => apiDesc.HttpMethod);
```

But unfortunately they don't actually apply any sortings.

I've also tried

```
Func<ApiDescription, string> sortKeySelector = (x =>
{
    return
        x.HttpMethod.Equals("GET", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            ? "0"
            : x.HttpMethod.Equals("POST", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                ? "1"
                : x.HttpMethod.Equals("PUT", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    ? "2"
                    : x.HttpMethod.Equals("DELETE", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                        ? "3"
                        : "4";
});
options.OrderActionsBy(sortKeySelector);
```

One thing I noticed is that swagger will group paths and then apply sorts. Is there a way to disable the path groupings?

[image]

The two gets should be together.

Comment: I guess, it's a question to Swagger UI: How does it render the page? You can sort values in any way, serialize them in JSON. But if Swagger UI resorts them, you need to use some other ways to influence Swagger UI.

Comment: @VladDX how do you know if swagger ui resorts them?

Comment: Educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

> At the moment I am trying to order by controller endpoints by
> httpmethod. Get/Post/Put/Delete

In my test I have tried in following way and its wroking as expected the way you want. You could give a shot.

```
public class SwaggerAPIDocsShorting : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {

            foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
            {
                foreach (var key in path.Value.Operations.Keys)
                {
                    var paths = swaggerDoc.Paths.OrderBy(e => e.Key).ToList();
                 
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(x => x.DocumentFilter<SwaggerAPIDocsShorting>());
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, I had a look at your output, your UnitOfWorkUsers endpoint are not sorted by http methods. 

They are sort by paths then by http method. I'm hoping for purely by http methods, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am checking again.

Comment: For path grouping it checks the route. When the Get endpoint and other type of endpoint does not have different route in the same controller it result with the issue.

Comment: In addition to this, I have checked swagger document as they said `operationsSorter` is Unavailable [`you could check here`](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

Swagger generate the UI with the json file:

[image]

In this part,We are configing the json file:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(...)
```

and you could even copy the content to a static json file and try as below to construct UI with the json file

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSwaggerUI(x => x.SwaggerEndpoint("/staticfile.json", "..."));
```

You could click on the link and get into it,then observe the structure of the data

```
"path":
  {
     "reletivepath1":
     {
      "get":{......},
       "post":{.....}
    },
    "reletivepath2":{
     "get":{.....},
     "post":{....},
     "put":{....}
    }
    }
```

When you  try with the C# codes

```
options.OrderActionsBy((apiDesc) => apiDesc.HttpMethod);
```

The json file could be modified to

```
"path":
      {
         "reletivepath2":{
         "get":{.....},
         "post":{....},
         "put":{....}
        },
         "reletivepath1":
         {
          "get":{......},
           "post":{.....}
        }
       
        }
```

or

```
 "path":
      {
         "reletivepath2":{
         "post":{....},
         "get":{.....},
         
         "put":{....}
        },
         "reletivepath1":
         {
          "post":{.....},
          "get":{......}
           
        }

        }
```

but it won't be like:

```
"path":
          {
             "reletivepath2":{
             "post":{....}
             
            },
             "reletivepath1":
             {
              "post":{.....}
            },
            "reletivepath2":{
             "get":{....}
             
            },
             "reletivepath1":
             {
              "get":{.....}
            }
    
            }
```

When it construct UI with the json file in order, the apis which shares the same path would look like in a group,I tried to copy the content of the json file to static file ,and modify it but all failed ,I don't think your requirement could be achieved now